# Infinite loop in php that change the variable from foo to bar and from bar to foo

Tags: php

So I have a really dumb question.
I am trying, in php, to code an infinite loop that constantly changes the variable $variable = foo to $variable = bar. After the variable = bar for it to detect and change it back to foo again forever if $number is divisible by 20.
Here's what I have so far, I limited it to 100 times, but how do i make it last forever? It also only changes foo to bar and keeps $variable = bar for the remainder of the loop. I think I have continue at the wrong spot? or do i need double continues somewhere.
THANKS!

```
$variable = "foo";

for ($number = 0; $number < 100; $number++) 
{
    echo $variable;
    if ($number % 20 == 0 && $number > 0) {
        echo "\n Divisible by 20 Changing variable";
        if ($variable = "foo") {
            $variable = "bar";
            echo ", $number\n";
        }
         if ($variable = "bar") {
            $variable = "foo";
            echo ", $number\n";
        }


         continue; 
} else {
        echo "\n no change";

}
}
```

Comment: Without digging into the code any further, this is most likely not what you want: `if ($variable = "foo")` - you wanted to use `==`, right? Same for the other `if`.

Comment: Also, there is absolutely no need for `$number > 0`, as you *know* that `$number` will always be at least 0.

Comment: And for your loop: `while($continue) { /* ... */ }` where `$continue` should be `true` for as long as you want the loop to continue.

Answer (score 1):

At a basic level to get the infinite loop you can do a couple of things:

1. You can use a `while(true)` loop.
2. You could use a broken for loop `for ($number = 0; $number != $number-1; $number++)`

The first one loops while the `true` values holds, so as long as you don't do anything like redefine what `true` means inside the loop you should be OK

The second one relies on the `$number` never being equal to `$number-1` and so just keeps incrementing the `$number` an alternative that I've seen used before is to omit the initialisation and condition entirely

```
for (;;) {
    print 'loop!';
}
```

Although in your case I'd go for the second one as it will allow you to access a `$number` inside your loop which you can then check the result of `$number % 20 == 0` in your logic.

Comment: How does one redefine what `true` means? What you (or the OP) wants is to use a boolean variable here, so you can break the loop in some way.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$variable = "foo";

for ($number = 0; $number < 100; $number++) 
{
    echo $variable;
    if ($number % 20 == 0 && $number > 0) {
        echo "\n Divisible by 20 Changing variable";
        if ($variable == "foo") {
            $variable = "bar";
            echo ", $number\n";
        }
         if ($variable == "bar") {
            $variable = "foo";
            echo ", $number\n";
        }


         continue; 
} else {
        echo "\n no change";

}
}
```

change:

```
if($variable = "foo") ==> if($variable == "foo")
if($variable = "bar") ==> if($variable == "bar")
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: sorry it doesn't change anything different. variable is always foo and never changes to bar.